# What is a secure way to compare route profile to logged in profile?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

Been curious about a secure way to check if the current route of `/username` is the current sessions profile, and if so it would conditionally let the owner edit their profile. What is the correct way to securely compare if the profile user and session user are the same?

To me, it seems like just comparing profile user ID or username to session ID or username is not effective.

Advice would be appreciated

Comment: Usually when we authenticate an user the 200 response comes back with the user info and a [JWT](https://jwt.io) token. We  can then store this token in the sessionStorage and use it to validate/reconciliate the session. Basically when you try to access a protected route you check if the token stored is valid (cause they can expire) and then can use the token to access the route. If it matches, proceed, else redirect to another non protected route or Access Denied page.

Comment: Well the profile page is both public and conditionally protected for edits (If the session user is accessing a public profile that is theirs, it would conditionally enable those features). So the only thing I can really compare is the data of that profile against the session user.

Comment: This [medium here](https://medium.com/@maison.moa/using-jwt-json-web-tokens-to-authorize-users-and-protect-api-routes-3e04a1453c3e) explains how to use JWT for accessing protected routes, the final part of it is kinda what I said in the previous comment but it comes with good explanation. So you'll see that after validation of the JWT it returns some user info and then you can use it to compare to the profile id to enable the features or not. Hope it helps =D